# Apache+PHP - different php versions per VHost

Tags: php, apache2

On my local dev maschine (Ubuntu), I have apache2 and different php version to develop different projects, managed over Vhosts.

Is there a way to configure each vhost to use a specific (already installed) PHP version? So for example:

- example1.local should use PHP 7.4
- example2.local should use PHP 8.0
- example3.local should use PHP 8.0
- example4.local should use PHP 5.6

Currently, I am always running for example `sudo a2enmod php{X} & sudo a2dismod php{Y} & sudo service apache2 restart` to switch versions, which is really anoying.

Comment: Did you end up resolving this issues? If yes, can you please help with the solution?.

Comment: No, not really. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using Apache. So you can use a .htaccess file and add there

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php74 .php
```

In this way your vhost uses php version 7.4

or with normal apache configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
        AddHandler php74-fcgi .php
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```